# The difference between two ways to access UIImageView under UITableViewCell of UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, reusability

I have a custom tableview to load news through webservice. I change image in each cell in method **cellForRowAtIndexPath**. After I got the right cell, I can access the image by two ways:

```
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:12];
    imageView.image = news.image;
```

or directly:

```
    cell.imageView.image = news.image;
```

when I use the **second** way, some images get into wrong cell while the first way give me a perfect result. It also happend in a callback method **iconDownLoadFinsh**.

I feel confused about it. Can anyone try to explain it? Please do not hesitate to ask questions. Thanks in advance.

```
- (void)iconDownLoadFinsh:(NSData *)imageData row:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:12];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    NewsModel *newsModel = [newsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    newsModel.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NewsCellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = newsTableViewCell;
        newsTableViewCell = nil;
    }

    // read from newsModel
    NewsModel *news = [newsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UILabel *label;
    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:news.title];
    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:11];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:news.description];
    UIImageView *imageView;
    imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:12];
    imageView.image = news.image;

    if (news.image == nil)
    {
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:IconPlaceHolder];

//      if (self.tableView.dragging == NO && self.tableView.decelerating == NO) {

            IconDownLoader *iconDownLoader = [[IconDownLoader alloc] init];
            iconDownLoader.url = news.imageUrl;
            iconDownLoader.delegate = self;
            iconDownLoader.indexPath = indexPath;
            [downloadArray addObject:iconDownLoader];
            [iconDownLoader start];
//      }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally always reset the cell properties in the method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

So I will do the following after getting the cell

```
if (cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = newsTableViewCell;
    newsTableViewCell = nil;
}
cell.imageView.image = nil; // Here resetting the imageview's image to nil.
```

Because you are reusing cells and if you do not clear old data, the cell data may get corrupt.

Comment: Hi @mbh thanks for your suggestion. It is good to do this. But is seems not contribute to this question. I tried but some images still stack to some others. **It is seems that cell.imageView.image can not find the right cell when fast scrolling **

Comment: Ideally I wont be loading images when fast scrolling. I would load images lazily when scrolling has stopped. Recommend going through Apple's LazyTableLoad (some name of that sort) sample code. You will do yourself and your app a big favor.

Comment: just saw you are actually using the lazyloading code! thumbs up. Now uncomment that line you commented out